# Decrease value in Python

Tags: python, recursion

Stuck on a problem where I am supposed to decrease the value of n by a value of k using Python Recursion.
If n = 10 and k = 2, my output should be:

```
10,8,6,4,2,0,2,4,6,8,10
```

n should decrease by k and then increase by k again.
I wrote the below code:

```
def pattern(n):
    k = 2
    if n <=0:
        print(n, end= ",")
        #pattern(n+k)            
    else:
        print(n, end = ",")
        pattern(n-k)

pattern(5)
```

but my output is:

```
5, 3, 1,-1
```

My answer should be:

```
5,3,1,-1,1,3,5
```

Comment: to prevent your result printing on a new line, use `print(n, end="")`

Comment: Your code isn't even correct. It'll go in infinite recursion.

Comment: For your example, if `k` is `3`, then how do you get `5, 3, -2`?

Comment: The code is incorrect, it does not do what is intended based on what you have explained.

Comment: I edited the code. Can you check it now

Comment: Even in your edited question, your desired output is of `n = 5, k = 2`, but you are using `k = 3`, which should give: `5,2,-1,2,5`

Comment: You really shouldn't be editing your own code this much. It's fine to clarify what your goal is, and fix example outputs, but fixing bugs in your own program can invalidate work that other people have put into answers.

Answer (score 3):

Here I've corrected your code:

```
def pattern(n, k, outer=True):
    print(n, end=",")
    if n > 0:
        pattern(n - k, k, False)
        if outer:
            print(n)
        else:
            print(n, end=",")

pattern(10, 2)
pattern(5, 3)
```

I've made `k` an argument to `pattern`.

I've also fixed the recursive algorithm. I think the most crucial part is that
you need to print the number again after the recursive step.

There is also some logic to make sure no comma is printed at the end. This is a
little convoluted, and if you're willing to use generators there's a much nicer
way (that also removes the side-effects of the function, which is a plus):

```
def gen_pattern(n, k):
    yield n
    if n > 0:
        yield from gen_pattern(n - k, k)
        yield n

def fmt_gen_pattern(n, k):
    return ",".join(map(str, gen_pattern(n, k)))

print(fmt_gen_pattern(10, 2))
print(fmt_gen_pattern(5, 3))
```

Here is the output generated by either of these:

```
10,8,6,4,2,0,2,4,6,8,10
5,2,-1,2,5
```

This is not the same output as you spelled out, but I'm pretty sure this is what
you meant.

Comment: The second approach with `yield` is basically what I just wanted to post. The first approach is IMHO pretty horrible, doing the print in the function with different end values, and should not be encouraged.

Comment: BTW, you can use `print(*gen_pattern(n, k), sep=",")` for the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of recursion lacks the base case that will stop the recursion. Hence, it'll recurse infinitely and abort eventually.

Here are two correct approaches to do it.

```py
def method1(current,direction,n,k):
    if current<=0:
        direction = 'Up'
    if direction=='Up' and current>=n:
        print(current,end=' ')
        return
    if direction=='Down':
        print(current,end=' ')
        method1(current-k,direction,n,k)
    else:
        print(current,end=' ')
        method1(current+k,direction,n,k)

def method2(n,k):
    if n<=0:
        print(n,end=' ')
        return
    print(n,end=' ') # This print shows decreasing n
    method2(n-k,k) # Recurse
    print(n,end=' ') # This print shows increasing n

n = 5
k = 2
# assert k<=n, "k cannot be greater than n" # Optional check
print('Method 1')
method1(n,'Down',n,k)
print('\nMethod 2')
method2(n,k)
```

---

Output

```
Method 1
5 3 1 -1 1 3 5 
Method 2
5 3 1 -1 1 3 5
```